# Excel VBA_Copy the first 2 or 3 columns and insert at every 3 or 4 column intervals

Tags: excel, vba, insert, copy, offset

I've been struggling for days using pieces of code from various projects and none seem to work for me.  I'd like to copy the first 2 to 3 columns and insert them every 3 to 4 columns to the right.  Seems simple enough but I have no idea what I'm doing!

Any help would be appreciated as I have a ton of data to do this to. Thank you.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Copy_Insert()

Range("A1:C1").EntireColumn.Select
Range("A:C").Copy
Range("A:C").Insert Shift:=xlRight

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: don't use `Select` in VBA. It's rarely needed and takes time.

If I understand correctly, you want to copy the contents of column A:C to D:F, G:I, J:L?

You could use:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

extraPairs = 3

For i = 1 To extraPairs
    lastColumn = i * 3

    Columns(1).Copy Columns(lastColumn + 1)
    Columns(2).Copy Columns(lastColumn + 2)
    Columns(3).Copy Columns(lastColumn + 3)
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Jannick, what I need it to do is copy A:C and insert it every 3 columns.  There are 200 columns and every 3, I need A:C inserted

Comment: Have you tried this code? You can change ```extraPairs``` to 67 (200/3)? It works for me.

Comment: I tried it but it's not inserting, it's copying over the data.  I'll add what I used to the question above

Answer (score 0):

This option isn't pretty and takes a while but here is what I ended up using and it worked fine:

Sub AutoInsert()

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 1 To .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 4
        For j = 1 To 3
            .Columns(i * 4 + j).Insert
            .Columns(i * 4 + j).Value2 = .Columns(j).Value2
        Next j
    Next i

End With
```

End Sub